Does "To go" in the following sentences when ordering edibles to consume in Australia mean "takeaway"?
I am wondering if "to go" in any of these sentences used when ordering something to consume means takeaway.
The first 2 come from this Australian show called "The Bureau of Magical Things", which is also set in Australia.

Uh. Can I get 3 juices to go, please?

I had a donut and a coffee to go.


The next 1 comes from this Mongolian waitress whom I am sort of mates with at this restaurant in CBD Sydney. She said this to other customers though. Not to me.

Would you like a bag to go? (While to go is not used here, she even said this to someone else) Would you like a takeout bag?)

The next 1 comes from another barista in the same shopping centre at Sydney whom I overheard asking a customer about a drink.

Would you like it to go?

These next 2 were said to me by some lady at a food truck in Circular Quay. There was no dine-in area near the food truck, and she just gave me my food in an open cardboard tray. She asked both of the 2 sentences in the same conversation.

Would you like a drink to go with your schnitty and chips?

Would you like to go with cheese sauce or gravy?



I read "to go" in its bare form as takeaway. But sentences (5) and (6) are not the same. There the phrase is "to go with" and it means "Would you like that item added to your order?"

What is a 'schnitty'? I think I might want one.

@Michael schnitty is slang for “schnitzel”, which is a fried chicken steak.

@Peter Same cause I used to live in America for most of my life. Growing up, it was always takeout I hear, but then, within the last 10 years, to go became the more common term. Same with bill. People in USA started to call it a check over the last 15 years when at a restaurant. In Australia, it is always bill.

Ah, like a Weiner Schnitzel which is usually a flattened thin veal cutlet with breadcrumbs, fried. I've seen pork and chicken ones too.

Does this help?

Does this answer your question? American equivalent of British "takeaway"

@Paul No, cause my question is talking about what to go means in each of these Australian sentences, not what Americans call "takeaway".

The research here that is lacking is this: Search on site:.au And please don't ask about Aussie English until you do. And if you are in Australia, your hits on google will all be for Australian sites. Now, when I enter site:.au from the States, I get a bunch of sites in Australia using takeaway. https://www.google.com/search?q=takeaway+site%3A.au&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1077US1078&oq=takeaway+site%3A.au&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCTkwMzhqMGoxNagCCLACAQ&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#ip=1

correction: When you enter the word takeaway.

It’s cause I get confused when Americanisms are used in Australia. Not once has an Australianism or British speech creeped into America aside from “no worries”, if that is even Australian exclusive.

Not in all of them
1, 2, and 3: yes - these are all references to takeaway orders.
3: maybe. If the intention is the same as "Would you like a takeout bag?" then, yes, but the word order is wrong. But "to go bag" is not a phrase that would be readily understood without context. Also, "takeout" is an Americanism—Australians say "takeaway." You mention the speaker is Mongolian, So I guess this is just a lack of fluency from an English as a second language speaker.
5: No. Here, "to go with" means as an accompaniment to, i.e. "Do you want a drink with your meal?"
6: No. "to go" is offering a choice between cheese sauce or gravy. "Would you like to go with ..." means "Would you like ...".

To go bag is common in America. Well, she knows what takeaway means cause she works at a restaurant, and I am sure she deals with customers ordering takeaway every shift. Also, her English is decent. I almost had trouble believing she wasn’t born in an English-speaking country. Yes, takeout is an Americanism while Australia uses takeaway, but taking something out is the same as taking something away.

The UK uses take-away too (or carry-out in Scotland), but the American to go is pretty well-known here from US films and TV.

I am pretty sure UK takeaway is also understood in USA even if no one there ever uses it, cause they have Peppa Pig, James Bond, Mister Bean, Johnny English, and a variety of British shows that stream too. In Australia, to go is well known cause even if everyone says “takeaway”, “to go” is written in many places to refer as “takeaway”.

Why did you ask, then? Your question implied that you didn't know what to go means!

@Megas - I don't think Peppa Pig eats takeaways, or discusses them. She's much too sensible.

@Megas also, James Bond is not famous for eating takeaway - he’s definitely an eat in guy.

@Megas The most important part, it seems to me, is that "to go" is a phrase in all but 5 and 6. In those it's just an infinitive. (Think of the difference: otherwise "I'd like coffee to go" means "I want coffee to depart from here!")

@Kate I was asking if "to go" meant "takeaway" in these 6 Australian sentences.

@Michael There was an episode in which the entire Peppa Pig family orders a takeaway. Its called "Takeaway", which is Season 2 Episode 3.

@Dale Same here, but James Bond is a british character.

@Andy I thought so too, but I needed second opinions cause its weird to call takeaway in Australia "to go", but "to go" is written a lot in NSW.

@Megas My impression is that this is one category where the regionally-specific terms are less bound than others. If someone talked about a "lorry" in US, pretty much everyone would understand the UK usage, but would look at them funny. I feel like "takeaway" wouldn't raise an eyebrow in US, even if "to go" is more common.

Agreed, cause in Sydney, people know what takeout and to go mean for takeaway. Also, it’s very common for menus to call chips “fries”, so everyone would know fries are chips. Then, comes stroller and pram. Everyone in Australia knows a pram is a type of stroller, but pram is never used in America.
